# Covariance in List

Tags: c#, .net

How can we design following model properly? I have two class Library. Library 2 has reference of Library 1. But Library 1 **doesn't** have reference of Library 2.

**Library 1:**

```
public class BaseData
{
   /*Some Properties*/
}

public class BaseGroup
{
   /*Some data*/
   public List<BaseData> DataList;
}
```

**Library 2:**

```
public class ChildData : BaseData
{
   /*Some more data*/
}

public class ChildGroup
{
   /*Some more data*/
   public List<ChildData> DataList;
}
```

How can I design these models so that I have one List. The List can be initiated at Library 1 and later updated at Library 2. Also from Library 2, I need to pass the `ChildGroup` object to Library 1 methods which takes `BaseGroup` as an argument.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Can't you just add a reference from library 1 to library 2?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: It really does, although it's not done terribly well.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm confused; covariance is a mathematical concept related to stochastic processes/random variables for me?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: That's not how the term is used in C#... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Bonner unfortunately I can't change the library references..

Comment: @MarcusMüller: The idea that two things can vary in some correlated way occurs in multiple branches of mathematics. The usage here comes to computer programming from category theory, not from statistics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't make `List<T>` covariant - it's invariant, and there's nothing you can do about that. You can't treat a `List<Apple>` as a `List<Fruit>` because you can't call `list.Add(new Orange())` on it, for example.

It seems to me that you should make your `baseGroup` class generic, with a constraint. Then you can make `childGroup` derive from it:

So - having fixed up the class names to follow .NET naming conventions:

```
public class BaseData {}

public class BaseGroup<T> where T : BaseData
{
    public List<T> DataList;
}

public class ChildData : BaseData {}

public class ChildGroup : BaseGroup<ChildData>
{
    // No need for a separate list here
}
```